Appium inspector keeps on loading on trying to inspect iOS elements
I am getting the below error after upgrading to iOS 18.0 for iOS automation also appium inspector keeps on loading while trying to inspect elements , Has anyone got this error and any possible solutions,
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: -[XCUIApplicationProcess waitForQuiescenceIncludingAnimationsIdle: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x30024c280
Xcode: Version 16.0 beta 5 (16A5221g)
Appium version: 2.11.15
ios device version: 18.0
Appium inspector version: App Version: 2024.9.1 Electron: 31.6.0
Node.js: 20.17.0

update xcuitest lastest, it works for me
appium driver update xcuitest


I have updated the xcuitest then in Xcode deleted the existing WDA project and again opened the WDA project with signing capabilities solved the issue.

I had this issue that started after updating XCode to v16. I updated everything under the sun to the latest versions - XCode, the iPhone itself, Appium, Appium Inspector, and XCUITest Driver. Still got this error. Finally, I went into the Developer Settings on the iPhone and tapped "Clear Trusted Computers", and then re-trusted the computer when it prompted. Ta-da, Appium Inspector suddenly worked again!
